# How to make my stamina regenerate slowly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help on my mobile open world game project. I have a player who can walk and runs when we press a button. I made a stamina wheel (like in zelda botw), and when my player run the stamina decreases. I have also put a regeneration coroutine that make the stamina regen. But because my maxStamina = 1, the time between it is empty and full is really fast. Here is my code :

```
public static StaminaUI instance;
private WaitForSeconds regenTick = new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
private Coroutine regen;

private void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}

void Start()
{
    fillAmount = maxFill;      
}

void Update()
{        
     if (Ybot.MoveSpeed > 5f)
     {
        UseStamina(0.015f);
     }  
     
     if (fillAmount < 0.01f)
     {
        Ybot.MoveSpeed = 0f;
        Ybot.animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        Ybot.animator.SetBool("isWalking", false);
    }

}

public void UseStamina(float amount)
{
    if (fillAmount - amount >= 0)
    {
        fillAmount -= amount;            

        if (regen != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(regen);
        }

        regen = StartCoroutine(RegenStamina());
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not enough stamina");
    }
}

private IEnumerator RegenStamina()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    while (fillAmount < maxFill)
    {
        fillAmount += maxFill/1;         
        yield return regenTick;           
    }
    regen = null;

}
```

Hope someone can help me to this little problem.

Comment: Can you please clarify what *you* expect `maxFill/1` to do?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you increment every `0.1` seconds I think it should be

```
fillAmount += maxFill / desiredDuration * 0.1f;
```

where `desiredDuration` is the time in seconds needed to completely fill the stamina if it is `0`.

---

Or as an alternative for smooth Updates instead of the `0.1` second steps you could do

```
while (fillAmount < maxFill)
{
    fillAmount += maxFill / desiredDuration * Time.deltaTime;      
    yield return null;           
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the both techniques are working perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Time.time and then do the regen if the TIme.time is > than a fixed interval. You have to realise that Update is called once per frame. This could mean it can be called anywhere between 30-90 times a second depending on your device's refresh rate.

Update is called once per frame so in your code you have to do something similar to this:

lastRegenTime and regenIntervals can both be floats (which can be expensive), but in Update the logic would be ->

```
            if (Time.time - lastRegenTime > regenInterval)
            {
                Regenerate();
            }
```

Set regenInterval to something low, and then set the incrementor for life at life+=0.02f; You can even do it more incrementally, or *=0.00002f;